# How to display the selected image in same in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c

JSON Url:

```
{
        "status": "200",
        "requestType": "productDisplay",
        "basePath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/",
        "bannerPath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/banner\/",
        "productPath": "http:\/\/192.168.0.33\/cartwebsite3\/cdn-images\/prd\/",
        "response": {
            "data": [{
                "product_id": "3",
                "seller_id": "1",
                "product_active": "on",
                "product_name": "Micromax Unite 3",
                "product_alias": "(Blue, 8 GB)",
                "product_sku": "21334",
                "product_manufacturer_country": "India",
                "product_manufacturer": "india",
                "product_min_add": "1",
                "product_max_add": "100",
                "short_description": "Slim, compact and user-friendly, the Micromax Unite 3 is a good combination of powerful performance and nifty features for a great smartphone experience.",
                "long_description": "Slim, compact and user-friendly, the Micromax Unite 3 is a good combination of powerful performance and nifty features for a great smartphone experience.",
                "product_quantity": "0",
                "quantity": "100",
                "status": "In Stock",
                "price_id": "4",
                "mrp_price": "5900.0000",
                "selling_price": "5099.0000",
                "offer_percentage": "",
                "product_weight": "130g",
                "offer_selling_price": "2000.0000",
                "offer_selling_percentage": "",
                "offer_selling_start_date": "1461621600",
                "offer_selling_end_date": "1469484000",
                "shipping_cost": "0.0000",
                "product_images": [{
                    "image_id": "18",
                    "product_id": "3",
                    "image_small": "",
                    "image_medium": "",
                    "image_large": "",
                    "original_res": "micromax-unite-3-951452579749.jpeg",
                    "image_type": "jpeg",
                    "added_date": "1452579749",
                    "added_user": "1",
                    "sort": "0"
                }, {
                    "image_id": "19",
                    "product_id": "3",
                    "image_small": "",
                    "image_medium": "",
                    "image_large": "",
                    "original_res": "micromax-unite-3-241452579749.jpeg",
                    "image_type": "jpeg",
                    "added_date": "1452579749",
                    "added_user": "1",
                    "sort": "0"
                }, {
                    "image_id": "20",
                    "product_id": "3",
                    "image_small": "",
                    "image_medium": "",
                    "image_large": "",
                    "original_res": "micromax-unite-3-301452579749.jpeg",
                    "image_type": "jpeg",
                    "added_date": "1452579749",
                    "added_user": "1",
                    "sort": "0"
                }],
                "basic_info": [{
                    "basic_id": "550",
                    "product_id": "3",
                    "option_name": "Features",
                    "option_description": "Android v5 OS",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                }, {
                    "basic_id": "551",
                    "product_id": "3",
                    "option_name": "Features",
                    "option_description": "8 MP Primary Camera",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                }, {
                    "basic_id": "552",
                    "product_id": "3",
                    "option_name": "Features",
                    "option_description": "2MP Secondary Camera",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                }, {
                    "basic_id": "553",
                    "product_id": "3",
                    "option_name": "Features",
                    "option_description": "Dual Sim (GSM   WCDMA)",
                    "have_connected": "0"
                }],
                "extra_info": [{
                    "type": "textfield",
                    "main_header": "Micromax Unite 3(Blue, 8 GB)",
                    "field_option": [{
                        "inside_single_title": "Specifications",
                        "basic_opt1": [{
                            "option_name_extra": "In the Box",
                            "option_desc_extra": "Handset, USB Cable, Charger, User Guide, Warranty Card, Battery, Hands-free"
                        }, {
                            "option_name_extra": "Sensors",
                            "option_desc_extra": "Light Sensor, Gravity Sensor, Proximity Sensor"
                        }, {
                            "option_name_extra": "User Memory\t",
                            "option_desc_extra": "4.9 GB for Apps and Phone Storage"
                        }, {
                            "option_name_extra": "Processor",
                            "option_desc_extra": "1.3 GHz   MTK 6582M, Quad Core"
                        }]
                    }]
                }],
                "category_list": [{
                    "category_id": "46",
                    "category_name": "ELECTRONICS",
                    "category_desc": "",
                    "category_image": "",
                    "category_thumbnail": "",
                    "category_image_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_title": "",
                    "category_meta_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_keyword": "",
                    "category_show_hide": "0",
                    "category_vanity": "electronics"
                }, {
                    "category_id": "48",
                    "category_name": "Mobiles",
                    "category_desc": "",
                    "category_image": "",
                    "category_thumbnail": "",
                    "category_image_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_title": "",
                    "category_meta_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_keyword": "",
                    "category_show_hide": "0",
                    "category_vanity": "mobiles"
                }, {
                    "category_id": "54",
                    "category_name": "Micromax",
                    "category_desc": "",
                    "category_image": "",
                    "category_thumbnail": "",
                    "category_image_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_title": "",
                    "category_meta_desc": "",
                    "category_meta_keyword": "",
                    "category_show_hide": "0",
                    "category_vanity": "micromax"
                }]
            }]
        },
        "request": {
            "postData": [],
            "getData": {
                "type": "productDisplay",
                "result": "json",
                "product_id": "3"
            }
        }
    }
```

Code:

```
-(void)navigateToNextPage :(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gest{

    UIImageView *theTappedImageView = (UIImageView *)gest.view;
    NSInteger index = theTappedImageView.tag;

    ViewController *orderView=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:orderView animated:YES];
    self.imgName.image = [imgid objectAtIndex:index];

//    orderView.stringcell=[product_id objectAtIndex:index];




}
```

How to display the selected image in same image in Xcode. image is clicked already but image is not displayed in output.

Comment: Why do you do `self.imgName.image` instead of `orderView.imgName` ? You didn't give any information to `orderView` to display something.

Comment: same like that this link.  http://i.imgur.com/LYBXFVu.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/LYBXFVu.png

Comment: image is clickable but image is not displayed.

Comment: orderview  is displayed in some error.       '-[NSNull componentsJoinedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x106b08af0'

Comment: I push to the image

Comment: you mean you want to carry that image to ViewController class?

Comment: no image to image class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>
{
    UICollectionView *_collectionView;
}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSArray *imagesArr;
    UIImageView *mainImageView;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    imagesArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sample1.jpeg", @"sample2.jpeg", nil];


    mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    mainImageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 300);
    mainImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArr objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self.view addSubview:mainImageView];


    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 60, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 60) collectionViewLayout:layout];
    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];

    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return imagesArr.count;
}

// The cell that is returned must be retrieved from a call to -dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 5, 50, 50);
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [cell addSubview:imgView];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(50, 50);
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"%@",[imagesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    mainImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

This is just a sample code. Replace/Assign "imagesArr" to your images array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: check updated answer and mention you question clearly that I didn't able to understand what you want.

Comment: click to this link

Comment: i want same method. image is clickable but it's not displaying.

Comment: ok. There are some images shown below. If you select one of them then you need to display selected image in main big imageView. right?